# NoMethodError: undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass - active_utils, factory_girl and more gems failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Out of nowhere, and without changing anything, I've started getting this error (and so did other people on the team).

This is happening for some gems (the ones specifying a git branch) and is only happening when we recreate the environment (in vagrant). We didn't change anything.

Any ideas? More info follows:

```
Using active_utils (2.0.0) from git://github.com/Shopify/active_utils.git (at v2.0.0)
NoMethodError: undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass
An error occurred while installing active_utils (2.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install active_utils -v '2.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.

Using factory_girl (2.6.5) from https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl (at 2.6.x)
NoMethodError: undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass
An error occurred while installing factory_girl (2.6.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install factory_girl -v '2.6.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

- Running "gem install active_utils -v '2.0.0'" works but bundle always
  fails.
- Cleared gem cache, but didn't help

Seems like it's all entries in Gemfile specifying a branch that started  failing.

```
gem 'active_utils', :git => 'git://github.com/Shopify/active_utils.git', :branch => 'v2.0.0'
gem "will_paginate", :git => "git://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git", :branch => "2-3-stable"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, turns out this was caused because of a recent upgrade to RubyGems. Forcing a previous version worked.

```
gem update --system 2.4.8
```

Answer (score 10):

While there's already an accepted answer, I ran into the same problem.

Ultimately, the cause was I was using an outdated bundler version and updating to the latest version fixed it. More info on the bug from here: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3560

The bug happens prior to bundler version 1.9.3.

You can update bundler by running `gem install bundler`
and then deleting the older bundler version via `gem uninstall bundler -v old.bundler.version`

If you're using rvm, I recommend installing this on the global gemset of your current ruby version by running `rvm use @global` before doing the install.

Comment: for me, the bug only appeared in bundler version `1.17.2`, it was fixed for me in `1.17.3`

Comment: 1.9.3 was key as all other versions of bundler prior had this issue.

Comment: Upgrading to `1.17.3` fixed it for me.

Comment: I had the same issue, I uninstalled my `1.9.0` version and installed `1.9.7` version. It works! Thx