# how to fix : Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I'm new to ruby, I was trying to run my first app but when I start the server I get this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":   In Gemfile:
    capybara (>= 2.15) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 3.15.1, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
Could not find gem 'nokogiri (~> 1.8)', which is required by gem 'capybara (>= 2.15)', in any of the sources.
```

I've tried many solutions and none worked, for example I tried `bundle install` `bundle update` `bundle exec`
I have ruby version 2.3.3,
rails version 5.1.7 when I run `rails -v` from outside the app folder, but from inside I get the same error as above

here is the gem file:

````
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.7'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sNnN.png
````

I ran `bundle pristine` and I got this:

````
--- ERROR REPORT TEMPLATE -------------------------------------------------------
# Error Report

## Questions

Please fill out answers to these questions, it'll help us figure out
why things are going wrong.

- **What did you do?**

  I ran the command `C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/bundle pristine`

- **What did you expect to happen?**

  I expected Bundler to...

- **What happened instead?**

  Instead, what happened was...

- **Have you tried any solutions posted on similar issues in our issue tracker, stack overflow, or google?**

  I tried...

- **Have you read our issues document, https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/bundler/doc/contributing/ISSUES.md?**

  ...

## Backtrace


NoMethodError: undefined method `specs' for nil:NilClass
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.2.0.rc.1/lib/bundler/cli/common.rb:72:in `ensure_all_gems_in_lockfile!'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.2.0.rc.1/lib/bundler/cli/pristine.rb:10:in `run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.2.0.rc.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:705:in `pristine'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.2.0.rc.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.2.0.rc.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.2.0.rc.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.2.0.rc.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.2.0.rc.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.2.0.rc.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.2.0.rc.1/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.2.0.rc.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.2.0.rc.1/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'


## Environment


Bundler       2.2.0.rc.1
  Platforms   ruby, x86-mingw32
Ruby          2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]
  Full Path   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe
  Config Dir  C:/ProgramData
RubyGems      3.1.4
  Gem Home    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  Gem Path    C:/Users/Moham/.gem/ruby/2.3.0;C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  User Home   C:/Users/Moham
  User Path   C:/Users/Moham/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  Bin Dir     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin
Tools
  Git         2.28.0.windows.1
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       not installed
  chruby      not installed


## Bundler Build Metadata


Built At          2020-07-02
Git SHA           d15da3db73
Released Version  true


## Gemfile

### Gemfile

ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.8'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.7'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]


### Gemfile.lock


<No D:/web developing/AAL/Ruby on rails/module 3/create app/my_first_app/Gemfile.lock found>


--- TEMPLATE END ----------------------------------------------------------------

Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue.

First, try this link to see if there are any existing issue reports for this error:
https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/search?q=undefined+method+%60specs%27+for+nil+NilClass&type=Issues

If there aren't any reports for this error yet, please create copy and paste the report template above into a new issue. Don't forget to anonymize any private data! The new issue form is located at:
https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/new?labels=Bundler```
````

Comment: Please post your `Gemfile`, first guess is that it is missing `source 'https://rubygems.org'`

Comment: There are plenty of versions of nokogiri that should match that dependency check. From version [`1.8.0`](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri/versions/1.8.0), all the way up to the latest, version [`1.10.10`](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri/versions/1.10.10). Unless the error message is actually a bit longer and there's something crucial you're not showing us, I'd say there must be something unusual in your `Gemfile`, such as specifying a non-default source for gems. Could you please try to show us the whole file, or at least enough information for us to reproduce the issue? See: [mcve].

Comment: I posted the whole error message, I checked for nokogiri version , it was 1.10.10, then I downgraded to 1.8.0 and removed 1.10.10 , still didn't work

Comment: @MohamadHasan are you still getting the same error or is it a different error message?

Comment: Can you post the entire error output?

Comment: @NickM the one in the main question is the entire error message

Comment: @TheGeorgeous I still get the same error

Comment: Did running `bundle install` complete successfully, or did it actually fail to install things? If it failed, please show the error. If it succeeded, then what happens when you run `bundle exec rails s`?

Comment: @TomLord ```bundle install``` runs successfully, but ```bundle exec rails s``` gives the same error as above

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Honestly at this point I'd rather look over your shoulder and see for my own eyes, because frankly that sounds impossible to me  .... You could try running `bundle pristine` to make absolutely sure that everything is installed. Check that it runs with *no error*. It should say, amongst many other things, that a certain version of `nokogiri` was installed successfully. And then run `bundle exec rails s` from the same folder. It *shouldn't* be possible for that error message to appear, if `bundle install` succeeded.

Comment: The only other possibility I can think of is if you have some funky setup running locally that you didn't mention, e.g. the rails application is dockerised.

Comment: I always run into trouble with nokogiri whenever installing rails on a new system. Eventually I got so sick of this that I scripted out the nokogiri build and installation separate from rails. You'll need to install a bunch of development dependencies if you're planning to do the same, I wasn't able to find a list so I just attempted rebuilding and reinstalling them one by one until it eventually worked.

Comment: @TomLord I have run ```bundle pristine``` and I posted the error message, I also didn't have any other installations, I just downloaded the installer form railsinstaller.org

Comment: Aha! An error message! Well, I googled the error message, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36453190/1954610) is the top result. Let's start from there. There's no point running the rails server until the gems are installed properly - and currently, for whatever reason, they're not.

Comment: @TomLord That link helped me, I uninstalled rails Installer, then used ruby installer, then used the command ```gem install rails```, created new application , run ```rails s``` , got a new error, that say (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen ) , trying to fix it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was solved following these steps:

1. uninstall rails installer and remove the folder manually.
2. setup ruby installer.
3. run `gem install rails`
4. install yarn.
5. restart pc
6. run `rails webpacker:install`.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your `Gemfile.lock` to confirm - but this looks like the capybara version is locked to '>=2.15' and the nokogiri version compatible with it is not present in the Gemfile.lock.

A quick fix is to set nokogiri to `'nokogiri', '~> 1.8'` explicitly in your Gemfile and see if the issue still persists. You might want to upgrade your capybara version to match a nokogiri version that's compatible with the other gems that require it

Comment: I posted the gemfile, I also added this line ```gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.8'``` still get the same error